# How do I only initialize on session instance in Express?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express

I have a website that has Angularjs on the front-end and Expressjs on the backend. I am tyring to implement authenticated and unauthenticated sessions for my users.

The problem I am having is that when a user goes to the website for the first time, there are several http requests that happen simultaneously to gather all of the data for the page. Since the user does not have a session cookie yet, Express generates a new session for each of these initial requests.

My server uses `app.use` on each request and verifies whether the passed in cookie is in the session store. If it isn't in the session store, then a new session is created. However, the server is called multiple times in a split second on page load, which causes four new sessions to be created - one for each request. How can I overcome this so that only one session is created?

Comment: Are you using express-session or passport-session? Reading through the documentation, it uses the header to pass information back in a cookie (if enabled) in order to identify the session. I would try to create an initial request to set the session rather than all requests at once. Have you been able to identify a method to slow down the additional 3 requests until the session has been initiated? https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: If you create the session on the request for the original HTML page, then all the subsequent requests from that page will have that session on it because those other requests can't start until after the browser has received the original HTML page.  Browsers request the page URL, receive the page URL content and THEN make other requests for resources that are listed in that content.

Comment: @BrianGerhards I am using express-session with an AWS MYSQL RDS session store. I have not been able to create a method to slow down the other requests. My main concern with making an initial request for the session is that the sessions expire. So if a user has an expired session and makes another request, then the server crashes.

Comment: By default the sessions do not expire (see https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options). Did you set a time for session expiration? _By default cookie.maxAge is null, meaning no "expires" parameter is set so the cookie becomes a browser-session cookie. When the user closes the browser the cookie (and session) will be removed._

Comment: Do you need a session before the user is authenticated? Otherwise just create the session after a successful user authentication.

Comment: @BrianGerhards yes, I set an expiration date. It is for E-Commerce. I need old shopping carts to expire.

Comment: @mscdex yes I need guest sessions for users to have guest shopping carts. The authenticated sessions work flawlessly, its the unauthenticated sessions that are created in bulk.

Comment: What methods have you come up with yourself so far? The initial thought that comes to mind is you need a lead request to set the session rather if it's when they come to your website for the first time or the first time they try to add an item to their cart. Otherwise you will run into the issue where you will have too many leads all seeing no session existing (in the header of the request).

Comment: @BrianGerhards I have thought of creating a lead request that would create a session when there is a brand new user, but I ran into the problem of users that had their sessions expire but were still on the page. Remember, this is Angularjs, so GET requests for routes do not occur very often when Angular handles routing. So if a user left a tab open with my website, then let the session expire before returning, there would be a problem.

Comment: You can access the time remaining in a session and report that back to the user as they navigate the website and set some sort of countdown timer with a modal or popup notifying them their cart will expire. I believe this conversation is going a little further than a discussion on how you can correct the multiple sessions issue you initially asked about. Coming up with a solution for the session timeout is a completely separate question. I would recommend starting a new question asking how to do this with Angular.

Comment: @BrianGerhards I will try to figure something out. I truly appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Another note in case I do not see the question... If you have not looked into Angular-UI's UI-Router, you can easily set up the routes and controllers and each time you access the page consisting of the specific controller (cached or not) you can have it make a call to check the session expiration. Good luck, Robert.

Comment: Do you really need to make multiple requests without a session? Can you e.g. template `data-has-session="false"` into the DOM and skip any subsequent non-static requests?